# assign value if empty

Tags: php, html

I call the profile photo with the instagram api, but if there is no profile photo, I want the image I set to replace it, but my code is not working, I have more code, this is just a part. My bad English, sorry.

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
$image_url2 = $arr['user']['profile_pic_url'];
if (empty($image_url2)) {
$image_url = "https://z-p42-instagram.fsaw1-7.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/119381356_363756831450146_3008355575418576013_n.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_ht=z-p42-instagram.fsaw1-7.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=TnWC8UN4NugAX9a6MH_&tp=25&oh=2405456ff153facda60364754a0a4cfe&oe=5FDEBDF6";
}else{
$image_url = $arr['user']['profile_pic_url'];
}
```

```
<div id="cerceve" class="cerceve">
                <img src="<?php echo $image_url; ?>" class="cerceve2" style="max-width:23%; border-radius:50%;">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Try `if (empty($image_url2) || true)` in your debugging attempts. See what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, I can't decipher why it *wouldn't* work if it truly is empty.  Using [Trim()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) may take out some invisible characters to get it to evaluate properly. I also added in [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) so we verify we have data before using it, as a good programming habit. Let's try this and see how it goes:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

// default $image_url to empty
$image_url = "";

// if we have profile_pic_url as a variable, lets use it
if (isset($arr['user']['profile_pic_url'])) {
    $image_url = trim($arr['user']['profile_pic_url']);
}

// If it is empty, default the picture
if (empty($image_url)){
    $image_url = "https://z-p42-instagram.fsaw1-7.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-19/s150x150/119381356_363756831450146_3008355575418576013_n.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_ht=z-p42-instagram.fsaw1-7.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_ohc=TnWC8UN4NugAX9a6MH_&tp=25&oh=2405456ff153facda60364754a0a4cfe&oe=5FDEBDF6";
}
```

Comment: Not working bro If there is a profile picture, it works. but if not, it gives an error.

Comment: Ok, well in the original post I don't see an "error" reference.  Do you have a reference of the error it gives?

Comment: I would say that's probably more of a hot-linking issue and it expects you to use the API.  Unrelated to your code.  Are you able to download that image, store it locally, and serve it from your own webserver?

Comment: The problem is the api, I will not use the API. Thank you bro.

Answer (score 0):

If an error is being thrown, I suspect it has to do with an invalid index issue.

Your OP does not specify any particular errors or the structure of the two types of responses, so its hard to be more specific.

Depending on which API is being used, it may have a flag property "has_profile_picture" or simular in responses.